# Проверить что массив упорядочен по убыванию

Tags: python

```
from random import randint 
 
def sort(nums): 
  swapped = True 
  while swapped: 
   swapped = False 
   for i in range(len(nums) - 1): 
    if nums[i] < nums[i + 1]: 
      nums[i], nums[i + 1] = nums[i + 1], nums[i] 
      swapped = True
 
a = [] 
for i in range(5): 
  a.append((1, 100)) 
 
print('first array :',a) 
sort(a) 
print('first sorted array :',a)
```

Comment: И в чём вопрос? Используйте кнопку править

Comment: Как сделать проверку?

Comment: Задать себе простой вопрос "Чем массив упорядоченный по убиванию отличается от любого другого? Какое свойство характерно для всех его элементов?", а потом написать соответствующий ответу алгоритм.

Comment: Я недавно начал кодить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def check_sort(array):
    return all([x > y for x, y in zip(array, array[1:])])
```

Функция `all` принимает итерируемый объект, она перебирает все его значения (приводя к булевому типу) и если они все дают `True`, то функция возращает `True`, иначе `False`. Понятно, чтобы сортировка была выполнена, все элементы должны в своем порядке убывать, поэтому мы создаем список и итерируемый по 0 и 1 индексу в исходном списке, далее 1 и 2 индексу и так далее, сравнивая их все по порядку. Прошу заметить, что конструкция `elem_1 > elem_2` возращает `True` или `False` в зависимости от того, верно ли сравнение, поэтому функции `all` ничего приводить не нужно, а только остается проверить, что все элементы `True`.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]